# Align mvc core webpage to the start of the screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I want to align the webpage content at the start of the screen.I have tried many solutions but nothing work. 
the below image will help in understanding my issue.
[image]

the index.cshtml view is below:

```
<div style="height: 100%">
<table class="table  align-content-lg-start">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-1">
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.DBId)
            </th>
            <th class="col-1">
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th class="col-1">
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.NID)
            </th>
            <th class="col-1">
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Address)
            </th>
            <th class="col-5">
                @Html.SortableHeaderFor(model => model.Mobile)
            </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <td class="col-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DBId)
            </td>
            <th class="col-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <td class="col-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NID)
            </td>
            <td class="col-1">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td class="col-5">
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mobile)
            </td>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using bootstrap. what you need to do is to find the class= "container". and change it to "container-fluid"